# How to add a view.addGestureRecognizer only once?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Every time `viewWillAppear` it calls 
`self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())`
to add a gesture recogniser.

How can I check if I haven't already added the recogniser ?
I know I can move it to `viewDidLoad`, but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the existence of your gesture instance like the following

```
 self.view.gestureRecognizers?.contains(yourgestureInstance)
```

`self.view.gestureRecognizers` give the array of all `gestureRecognizers` that have been added to the view.

Answer (score 1):

`viewWillAppear:` will call everyTime whenever your viewController comes on to the screen.

`viewDidLoad:` will be called only once.

If you don't want to move the code to `viewDidLoad:` in this case add one boolean variable into your ViewController.

delcare `isRevealPanGastureAdded` variable outside of the `viewDidLoad:`

```
var isRevealPanGastureAdded : Bool = false
```

In `viewWillAppear:` write below code.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);

        //this will be called only once                 
        if self.isRevealPanGastureAdded == false {
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        self.isRevealPanGastureAdded = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can add boolean property to detect that `viewWillAppear` was called before

2) You can store added gesture recognizer in property and if it is not `nil` don't add it again

3) You can remove added gesture recognizer in `viewWillDisappear`/`viewDidDisappear`